# Mercurial - hg update to a specific date on a named branch

Tags: date, mercurial, branch

I'm am currently working on a project which has several mercurial repositories. Each mercurial repository contains the source code for either a library or a binary, all of which are being actively developed.

You can imagine that compatability between products created from each repository can quickly become a problem. One way to relieve this problem is to update each local repository to be on compatible branches and then update to a particular date on these branches - with the view that at any point in time the branches were compatible.

On a named branch, say V0.X, at V0.1 tag

```
hg identify
```

gives

```
934ad264137e (V0.X) V0.1
```

Then update to a particular date ( I still want to stay on the V0.X branch )

```
hg update -d "<10/28/11"
```

now identify

```
hg identify; hg branch
```

gives

```
51a072771de7 tip
default
```

Does anyone know how to update along a named branch to a date without the danger of jumping off to another branch?

Any help would be appreciated.

Jon.

Comment: Good question, but the documentation for `hg help update` says: `-d --date DATE  tipmost revision matching date`. Not sure what that means, tho ... :(

Answer (score 3):

```
hg help revset
```

> ```
> "branch(string or set)"
>   All changesets belonging to the given branch or the branches of the
>   given changesets.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> "date(interval)"
>        Changesets within the interval, see "hg help dates".

give us workflow like

- hg log -r "branch('V0.X') and sort(date('<10/28/11'), date)"
- find revision N in list
- hg update -r N

Comment: well, pp 1-2 can be converted to some oneliner, which, used as -r parameter of update, give us requested result

Comment: Yeah, I believe the following one-liner does what was requested: hg update -r "branch('V0.X') and date('<10/28/11')"